# CSS how to scale on the bottom instead of the top of an image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a background image on my front page which is supposed to cover the entire screen.

It's a fairly large image, 2560x1714

However, most screen resolutions won't match that. And when the aspect ratio is at it's max. It starts "zooming" in on the picture, to fill it to the width of the screen. However, when it does this, it zooms in on the top of the picture.

I need it to zoom in on the bottom, as that's where I want the focus to be.

Here's an image of what I want to see: (the beach basically)

[image]

However, when I make my browser wider, it "zooms" in on the top of the image.

[image]

It's completely fine that it changes how much I can see of the image. But I need it to be opposite of what it does now. So the beach is always at the bottom of the screen no matter what.

Here's the CSS for my header:

```
header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-height: auto;
text-align: center;
color: #FAFAFA;
background-image: url("../img/header-2.jpg");
background-position: top;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover
}
```

Any ideas on how I can make it, so I see less of the sky, instead of less of the beach/surfboard?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-position: top;
```

to

```
background-position: bottom;
```